# Load JButton Icons Asynchronously

Tags: java, api, asynchronous, jbutton, okhttp

I have an application that pulls data from an API on startup and displays them in a grid of JButtons. I have successfully displayed and generated the JButtons based on the API response, however my issue is each Button needs to have an icon that is also being pulled from the API directly into the JButton icon.

Achieving this is fine but my problem is it then takes like 10 minutes for the app to start since it has pull each image icon one by one synchronously.
P.S. I'm using OkHttp as my http client.

Can someone please help me in finding a way to perhaps load the buttons and then load the images gradually as they're being fully pulled from the API.

How can I do this?
How can do this asynchronously?

I have tried looking everywhere but I haven't been able to apply the answers I'm finding to my problem successfully.

Here's the code segment of this problem.

Thank you in advance!

```
static final MediaType JSON = MediaType.get("application/json; charset=utf-8");

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

// api post method
String post(String url, String json) throws IOException {
    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, json);
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url(url)
        .post(body)
        .build();
    try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) {
        return response.body().string();
    }
}

// api call
try {
        String json = "";
        String response = post("http://myapi.com", json);

        JSONObject JsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray devices = JsonResponse.getJSONArray("response");

        int rows = (devices.length() / 4) + 3;
        resultsPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(rows, 0, 20, 20));

        for(int d = 0; d < devices.length(); d++){

            // store device details
            JSONObject selectedDevice = devices.getJSONObject(d);

            // create button
            JButton device = new JButton();

            // style button
            Border lineBorder = new LineBorder(new java.awt.Color(238, 238, 238));
            Border padding = new EmptyBorder(0, 10, 0, 0);

            device.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/assets/shield_32.png")));

            device.setIconTextGap(20);
            device.setText(devices.getJSONObject(d).get("name").toString());
            device.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
            device.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
            device.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 0, 12));
            device.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
            device.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            device.setBorder(new CompoundBorder(lineBorder, padding));
            device.setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
            device.setFocusable(false);

            // event handling
            device.addActionListener((java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) -> {
                System.out.println("Selected: " + ((JButton) evt.getSource()).getText());
                deviceNameLbl.setText(((JButton) evt.getSource()).getText());

                deviceImgLbl.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/assets/shield_350.png")));
                getDevicePattern(selectedDevice.get("deviceModelID").toString());

                CardLayout card = (CardLayout)mainPanel.getLayout();
                card.show(mainPanel, "material_design");
            });

            // add button to panel
            resultsPanel.add(device);
        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ISoD.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to solve this problem myself.

I used the SwingWorker class to asynchronously set the image icons as they are being pulled from the API. It's the perfect effect I was looking for!

Here's the full solution:

**Main Class (JFrame)**

```
static final MediaType JSON = MediaType.get("application/json; charset=utf-8");
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

String post(String url, String json) throws IOException {
    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, json);
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url(url)
        .post(body)
        .build();
    try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) {
        return response.body().string();
    }
}

try {
        String json = "";
        String response = post("http://my-api.com/images", json);

        JSONObject JsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray devices = JsonResponse.getJSONArray("response");

        int rows = (devices.length() / 4) + 3;
        resultsPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(rows, 0, 20, 20));

        for(int d = 0; d < devices.length(); d++){

            // store device details
            JSONObject selectedDevice = devices.getJSONObject(d);

            // create button
            JButton device = new JButton();

            // extracting icon url from api response
            URL imageURL = new URL(devices.getJSONObject(d).get("brandImage").toString());

            // style button
            Border lineBorder = new LineBorder(new java.awt.Color(238, 238, 238));
            Border padding = new EmptyBorder(0, 10, 0, 0);

            device.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/assets/stock_image.png")));
            device.setIconTextGap(20);
            device.setText(devices.getJSONObject(d).get("name").toString());
            device.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
            device.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
            device.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 0, 12));
            device.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
            device.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            device.setBorder(new CompoundBorder(lineBorder, padding));
            device.setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
            device.setFocusable(false);

            // add button to panel
            resultsPanel.add(device);

            // asynchronously load images from api response
            new ImageWorker(imageURL, device).execute();
        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ISoD.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

**SwingWorker Class**

```
public class ImageWorker extends SwingWorker<ImageIcon, Void>{

URL imageURL;
ImageIcon brandImage;
JButton device;

public ImageWorker(URL imageURL, JButton device){
    this.imageURL = imageURL;
    this.device = device;
}

@Override
protected ImageIcon doInBackground() throws Exception {
    brandImage = new ImageIcon(imageURL);
    Image rawBrandImage = brandImage.getImage();
    Image newimg = rawBrandImage.getScaledInstance(32, 32,  java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    brandImage = new ImageIcon(newimg);
    return brandImage;
}

@Override
protected void done() {
    // leave as default zagg shield icon if no brand icon is returned by api
    if (brandImage.getIconWidth() == 32 && brandImage.getIconHeight() == 32) {
        device.setIcon(brandImage);
    }
  }
}
```